# Upload file in mobile local path to parse.com in my ionic 2 application

Tags: parse-platform, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to upload an audio file to my parse server. I got the audio file by [cordova-plugin-media-capture](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) plugin.

```
  var captureSuccess = (mediaFiles) => {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      this.media = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
    }
  };

  navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1, duration: 120});
```

My result (local path for audio file) saved in **this.media**. But refer to [Parse.com Javascript sdk guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#files).

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
```

The file is from:

```
<input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload">
```

My question is how to convert my local file path **this.media** to **file** when I create Parse.File? Thanks.

Comment: Or is it possible to create a file object manually as the result got from <input type="file">?

Comment: My final solution is to use Cordova File Plugin to read the file and upload it as base64 data.